# Socket python Chat & File transfer

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm currently trying to implement a chatroom + file transfer application with python 3 and socket for a university task.
I'm using code from this GitHub repo https://github.com/an09mous/pyChat for the chatroom and wrote some code for the file transfer:

Client send method:

```
file = open(filename, "rb")
file_data = file.read(1024)
s.send(file_data)
file.close()
print("Data has been transmitted successfully")
```

Server receive method:

```
filename = 'ClientTransfer2.txt'
file = open(filename, 'wb')
file_data = conn.recv(1024)
file.write(file_data)
file.close()
print("File has been received successfully.")
```

I tried to merge both codes together by checking if the last message is "Send file", and if so sending a file from the client and receiving it on the server:

Server receive:

```
try:
            msg = conn.recv(4096)
            if msg:
                if decodeMessage(msg) == "Send file":
                    receiveFile(conn)
                print(type(msg))
                msg = clientName + ": " + decodeMessage(msg)
                print(msg)
                broadcast(encodeMessage(msg), conn)
            else:
                removeClient(conn)
                break
```

Client send:

```
while True:
        try:
            msg = input()
            if msg == "Send file":
                sendFile()
            else:
                msg = encodeMessage(msg)
                server.send(msg)
        except:
            print("Failed to connect to server!")
            break
```

Now I always get the content of my .txt file that I'm trying to send printed as a "chat message" instead of a file being written to the directory.

I understand that this is due to both chat messages and files being coded into bytes and sent. How can I differentiate between a file that is being sent and a text message?

Googleing that topic, I have not found an implementation of both chat + file transfer for Python, but if you know one, please let me know so I can try to understand their code and maybe get inspired by that solution ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to figure out an encapsulation for different message types. While you're at it, you'll also need to encode the message length; given TCP is a stream-oriented protocol, you wouldn't be able to know when you've received all of a given message otherwise.

Comment: you could pass some identifier that specifies if the message is text for a file.

Comment: Don't use the code from that github repo, it's wrong, wrong, wrong.